# I suspect my website is sending wrong HTTP Headers

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, http-headers, cache-control

This has been bugging me for a while now. Whenever I try to share my website link on Facebook or another link-sharing site, the link-sharing site either removes the URL (like it doesn't recognize it as valid) or in Facebook's case - it can't retrieve meta-data automatically.

I'm *pretty* sure that it used to work. However, Googling / StackOverflowing for this problem is a difficult task, since I have no idea what possibly could create this problem.

I've tried to create a static .HTM file on my website, and that works fine:
[test.htm](http://www.orango.nu/test.htm)

My default home page is a classic ASP (yeah I know, PHP version in the works) which uses IIS 7 URL Rewrite module.

I've tried to check the resultcodes and headers for both [test.htm](http://www.orango.nu/test.htm) and my [default home page](http://www.orango.nu/) on this page: http://gsitecrawler.com/tools/Server-Status.aspx

This is the results:

**test.htm**

```
URL=http://www.orango.nu/test.htm
Result code: 200 (OK / OK)
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Feb 2011 10:16:55 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0d877a654c4cb1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 04 Feb 2011 10:40:08 GMT
Content-Length: 452
```

**default home page /**

```
URL=http://www.orango.nu
Result code: 200 (OK / OK)
Cache-Control: public
Content-Length: 13463
Content-Type: text/html; Charset=UTF-8
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDSCSADCAR=DLPBECCBGDJMADLEPMOMHDDC; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 04 Feb 2011 10:24:22 GMT
```

The first 4 lines of my default.asp (/) file are:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html"  
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"  
Response.CodePage = 65001  
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
```

Does ***anyone*** have an idea what could be wrong and/or how to fix it? Any help or advice would be much appreciated, because this is driving me to the edge of madness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content-type looks wrong on your homepage...

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 13463
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8,text/html; Charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 04 Feb 2011 10:48:39 GMT
```

I also don't see the need, at least for the homepage, for the `cache-control: private` header.

Comment: I've tried to add Response.CacheControl="public" now and removed the AddHeader "Content-Type". Also, I have no idea why the server per default insists on using cache-control: private. :-|

Comment: I can't see anything else that may be wrong with your headers. FWIW, it may be something else.

Comment: Turns out it was the cache-control: private, that prevented sites like Facebook to access the contents automatically. Oh, and the changes I made was just to add cachecontrol=public in the header, but the change didn't affect anything until a couple of hours later, which is why it seemed like it didn't work at first. :-)